# How to reset sequence numbers using Java QuickFIX

Tags: java, quickfix, quickfixj

Currently I am working on Java Project where trying to use QuickFIX engine.
But every time getting below message:

```
MsgSeqNum too low, expecting 3 but received 2
```

For some security reason, can't share the whole Java file and config, but code portion can be shared in customized way.

What I want from here is, if there is any Java sample using QuickFIX where above error point has been fixed.

NB:
Apologies if the same question is there.
Please help me to find that one also.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually set the sequence numbers using APIs:

Session.lookupSession(session_).setNextSenderMsgSeqNum();
Session.lookupSession(session_).setNextTargetMsgSeqNum();

You can also refer: [How to set sequence numbers manually in QuickFixJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878316/how-to-set-sequence-numbers-manually-in-quickfixj)

Comment: thanks for your answer. This time my issue was others and fixed that already. But I also think that your answer should work and will use this code if required in future.